# How to handle a search by CSS class in Beautiful Soup bs4 coding style

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup

After [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Searching%20by%20CSS%20class) it should look like this for bs3:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
soup.find("div", {"class":"box text"})
```

And after [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) for bs4 like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
soup.find("div", class_="box text")
```

For me only the bs3 style works. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
    example:

```
<div class="box text" align="center">
```

Comment: The latter syntax works only if your class attribute matches *exactly* (`'text box'` or `'box text callout'` won't match); use a regular expression if you need to match at lest two classes where more are possible.

Comment: You'll need to give us some input examples where the BS3 version works but the BS4 version doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer CSS selector `select('div.box.text')`. It's easy and it can find classes on various positions in attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<div class="box text" align="center"></div>
<div class="box" align="center"></div>
<div class="text" align="center"></div>
<div class="text box" align="center"></div>
<div class="text somethingelse box" align="center"></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print("soup.find_all('div', {'class':'box text'}):")
print('*' * 80)

for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"box text"}):
    print(div)

print("\nsoup.find_all('div', class_='box text'):")
print('*' * 80)

for div in soup.find_all("div", class_="box text"):
    print(div)

print("\nUsing soup.select('div.box.text'):")
print('*' * 80)

for div in soup.select('div.box.text'):
    print(div)
```

Prints:

```
soup.find_all('div', {'class':'box text'}):
********************************************************************************
<div align="center" class="box text"></div>

soup.find_all('div', class_='box text'):
********************************************************************************
<div align="center" class="box text"></div>

Using soup.select('div.box.text'):
********************************************************************************
<div align="center" class="box text"></div>
<div align="center" class="text box"></div>
<div align="center" class="text somethingelse box"></div>
```